# File path handled differently in Safari and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, safari

I downloaded the floppy bird html game from github and hosted it on my server here: http://ping3.com/games/floppy.htm

It loads just fine in chrome but on mobile safari it loads only some of the elements (like background). It probably has something to do with the relative paths because I changed the dir structure a bit by moving everything except index.htm in a sub folder (also changed the paths in code).

When I don’t change the dir structure it loads correctly in both chrome and mobile safari: http://ping3.com/games/winged/

Comment: If a network request is failing, then you can look in the inspector and find the error. Please include that in your question.

Comment: The only place it is not working is on mobile safari. So I don't know what is happening behind the scene (unless there is a way to see).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a cache issue. After a hard refresh it is working as expected. Ctrl + Reload button click on Mac and Settings>Safari>Advanced>WebsiteData on iOS. Thanks.